# Form submit on enter needs at-least one input type = "text" element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I observed that form element should require at least one input type = "text" element to submit the form on enter press.

Here is my code :

```
<form ng-submit="executeFunc()">
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

But what if we don't have the first input type ="text" element, rather we have radio button or select box, checkbox.
If this is the scenario then how to submit the form on enter.

I want to know is it as per W3C standards, we need to provide atleast one input type "text" element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As regards to the added question “as per W3C standards, we need to provide atleast one input type "text" element ?”, the answer is that no HTML specification *requires* that a form be submittable by pressing Enter at all. The specs just describe (vaguely) what browsers *may* do.

Originally, the idea was that you can submit a form containing only one text input field (and possibly radion buttons and checkboxes) by hitting Enter after filling in the input field. This was deemed useful for simple forms, typically search forms or subscription forms, to make things faster for the user.

Later, the idea was often extended to forms that have several text input fields. This often causes problems, since the user might press Enter before filling in all the fields he should have filled. Yet, this is how modern browsers generally behave (provided that there is a submit button in the form).

HTML5 follows the tradition, just describing what browsers might do, though deviating from the tradition by strongly recommending (but not requiring for conformance) the common behavior, in the [Implicit submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-0http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-0) section:

> If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly
>   (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text
>   field is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a
>   form whose default button has a defined activation behavior must cause
>   the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on that default
>   button.
>
> [...]
>
> **Note:** There are pages on the Web that are only usable if there is a way to
>   implicitly submit forms, so user agents are strongly encouraged to
>   support this

(Regarding the original question, the answer is that you need to handle such things in JavaScript, and @bardznusny’s answer shows one concise way of doing that.)

Comment: Re: "*…provided that there is a submit button in the form*". Testing in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and OmniWeb shows that a submit button is not required, only a single text input.

Comment: Thanks alot @Jukka K. Korpela,

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger `click` event on submit button each time `enter` key is pressed.

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click();
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1eLyeghh/1/

Comment: Note that [*event.which*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.which) is deprecated, [*event.keyCode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.keyCode) should be used instead. Also consider`document.forms[0].submit()`.

Comment: This appears to be a correct answer to the original question (which has now been modified to contain another question, too). Using `document.forms[0].submit()` is possible, too, but it causes normal HTML form submission operations (HTML5 form data validation, `onsubmit` handler) to be bypassed.

Comment: @bardzusny : I want to know is it as per W3C standards, we need to provide at least one input type "text" element ?

Comment: @robiee - no, no "need" per se for each <form> to contain at least one text `<input>`.

Comment: @RobG: I updated the answer to use `event.keyCode`, thanks! I'm not touching the submitting part, reasons outlined by Jukka K. Korpela.

Comment: @bardzusny—fine, but what if there is no input type submit, or there was a button type submit instead? I guess the alternative is to manually dispatch a submit event on the form.

Comment: @bardzusny—sorry, but [*keyCode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.keyCode) is deprecated too!! Need to use [*event.key*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.key).

Comment: @RobG `event.key` is supported only by Firefox, take a look at the compatibility table. Yeah, it turned out to be "deprecated vs deprecated" scenario. But AFAIK there are no (supported, "not deprecated") alternatives, right now.

Comment: @bardzusny—yes, it's a PITA. Also, the *submit* method used to act just like the button (DOM 2 HTML specification), but it was changed. Nearly as messy as mouse/pointer device buttons. Dispatching events on the form to trigger submission doesn't seem to work either.